# From one vector delete all elements of another vector in r

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 vectors

```
vec_1
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[35] 10 11 12 13 14  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

vec_2
 [1] 12  3 13  3 14  4 10  8  9  5  7  5 13 11  6 10  8  8 14 12  6 11  8  5  3  6
```

I want to delete all elements of `vec_2` from `vec_1`
And sure, that function `setdiff` is not the case,because, for example, in `vec_2` there are two 10s values. And I want to delete only to 10(not all four values of 10).

EDITED: expected output:

```
vec_1
[1] 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 9 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14
```

How can i do this in r?

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  Also, please use `dput` to show the vectors

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea via `union`

```
unlist(sapply(union(vec_1, vec_2), function(i) 
                     rep(i, each = length(vec_1[vec_1 == i]) - length(vec_2[vec_2 == i]))))
#[1]  2  2  2  2  3  4  4  4  5  6  7  7  7  9  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, not the best solution but here is one way.

I created a simplified example.

```
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5)
vec2 <- c(1, 3, 5)

#Converting the frequency table to a data frame
x1 <- data.frame(table(vec1))
x2 <- data.frame(table(vec2))

#Assuming your vec1 has all the elements present in vec2
new_df <- merge(x1, x2, by.x = "vec1", by.y = "vec2", all.x = TRUE)
new_df

#  vec1 Freq.x Freq.y
#1    1      3      1
#2    2      1      NA
#3    3      1      1
#4    5      1      1

#Replacing NA's by 0

new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- 0

#Subtracting the frequencies of common elements in two vectors
final <- cbind(new_df[1], new_df[2] - new_df[3])
final

# vec1  Freq.x
#1    1      2
#2    2      1
#3    3      0
#4    5      0

#Recreating a new vector based on the final dataframe

rep(final$vec1, times = final$Freq.x)
# [1] 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a simple for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(vec2)){
    i=which(vec1 %in% vec2[i])[1]
    vec1=vec1[-i]
}
```

You just identify the first position and remove from the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
for (el in vec2[vec2 %in% intersect(vec1, vec2)])
  vec1 <- vec1[-which(vec1==el)[1]]
sort(vec1)
 #[1]  2  2  2  2  3  4  4  4  5  6  7  7  7  9  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14
```